# Variables with decimal format lose the decimal point

Tags: ssis

I have an *Execute SQL Task* control flow with a SQL that would be, simplified, something like this:

```sql
select sum(Amount) from Sales where Customer = ?
```

This generates a single row, single column rowset with an output with something likethis:
|sum(Amount)|
|-|
|123456.78|

I have mapped this output to a variable (let's say `User::SalesAmount`) in the package with format **decimal**.

But then, when the task is finished and I check the value of the variable in the Watch inspector or with a Script Task the value stored in the variable appears as `12345678`, it has kept all the digits but removed the decimal point.

I have also tried to set the format of the variable to `double`, but I get the same result.

The only solution I found is to declare the variable as `String` and make a Data Conversion later. But I guess if somebody has already found the same problem and what solution the applied.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this changing the Package LocaleID from *Spanish (Spain)* to *English*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a simple reproduction, I created a package that has an Execute SQL Task and a Variable named User::SalesAmount of data type Decimal and an initial value of 0.

[image]

The query used is a literal

```
SELECT 123456.78 AS SalesAmount;
```

*General* tab set as

[image]

*Result* Set tab set as

[image]

Results show my Variable of @[User::SalesAmount] has retained the decimal values.

[image]

Were I in your place, I would identify what happens when I provide an explicit value for your SalesAmount as I have shown. Then you'll know: Is is the query itself or something with 1) how I assign the value 2) the variable to which I am assigning 3) something else entirely.

Comment: I have exactly copied what you've done and I'm still getting the 12345678 as value instead of 123456.78.

I'm using SQL Server and you seem to be using something different

Comment: Not sure why you'd think I'm using something other than SQL Server. I am using SSIS 2022 with SQL Server 2017 as my query source. I would try adding screenshots to your question. Capture the same areas as I do with the Execute SQL Task + a screenshot of your Variables window and let's see if we can find the difference

Comment: I tested also in a production environment and there it works. It's some kind of misconfiguration in my local environment.

Answer (score -2):

Column metatype should be

```
Column name     Datatype
name_1           NUMBER(10,2)
```

Comment: Where do I set the Column Metatype attribute? This is not a dataflow task

Comment: databsae ,table ,column metatype